# Multiple web-sockets in a front-end application

Tags: websocket, architecture, frontend, infrastructure

This is a "design" or a "best-practices" theoretical question.

Most commonly web apps that use websocket connections use at most one websocket connection. However, there are no limitations for a web app to use more e.g. 10. More websocket connections might be chosen for data separation or clean code use cases (obviously there's more).

My question is - *Is there a significant difference (in terms of performance, uptime, etc.) between having a one open websocket and having, let's say, ten open websockets in your webapp?*

Also, imagine these two architectures. In the upper one the webapp opens as many websocket connections as it needs. In the lower one the webapp has always only one websocket connection to a "proxy" server and that "proxy" server opens websocket connections to as many endpoints as needed.

[image]

Question - *Could you point some theoretical (practical) insights of why would one choose one architecture over the other? P.S. the lower one seems to be over-complicated.*

Thank you!

Comment: What is the use-case of websockets in this solution? What kind of communication pattern do you expect?

Comment: Nothing specific. It's just something that has popped into my mind. Let's say it's a two-way communication - sometimes frontend decides to send some frames, sometimes backends decide to send some frames.

Comment: As with everything; it depends. The amount of open connections will no doubt have an impact in performance if you expect to have many concurrent users. Even for idle connections, connection tracking is not free. For most backend stacks this will directly translate to RAM usage. ... there are reasons why the web is moving less connections (HTTP/2 /3), not more.

Comment: Most of the problems you will face with this approach are going to be on the back-end. I don't think there is a definitive answer to your question thus I am linking an article where this and many other things re-websockets are detailed. https://medium.com/draftkings-engineering/lessons-learned-websocketapi-at-scale-604617a54cdb

The best practice is to try to keep your system simple, and with websockets problems with state, authentication, security, load-balancing and others are waay more prominent than number of sockets on the client.